# Golang gqlgen error trying to import model into resolver.go

Tags: go, graphql, go-modules

Hello I was playing arround with Golang and wanted to try GraphQL instead of a RESTful approach.
So I decided to use https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen to implement it.

I followed to getting started guide and everything went fine until I pasted the resolver.go code.

My Folder structure:

```
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── gqlgen.yml               
├── graph
│   ├── generated            
│   │   └── generated.go
│   ├── model                
│   │   └── models_gen.go
│   ├── resolver.go          
│   ├── schema.graphqls      
│   └── schema.resolvers.go  
└── server.go
```

My resolver.go

```
package graph


import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

type Resolver struct {
    todos []*model.Todo
}

func (r *mutationResolver) CreateTodo(ctx context.Context, input model.NewTodo) (*model.Todo, error) {
    todo := &model.Todo{
        Text: input.Text,
        ID:   fmt.Sprintf("T%d", rand.Int()),
        User: &model.User{ID: input.UserID, Name: "user " + input.UserID},
    }
    r.todos = append(r.todos, todo)
    return todo, nil
}

func (r *queryResolver) Todos(ctx context.Context) ([]*model.Todo, error) {
    return r.todos, nil
}
```

Obviously it would throw me an error since I did not import the model.

So I tried to import it like that `"[MODULENAME]/graph/model"`
This resulted in:

```
graph/schema.resolvers.go:14:28: (*mutationResolver).CreateTodo redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at graph/resolver.go:18:6
graph/schema.resolvers.go:18:25: (*queryResolver).Todos redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at graph/resolver.go:28:6
```

If I try `[MODULENAME]/model`

It throws me this error:

```
cannot find module providing package [MODULENAME]/model: unrecognized import path "[MODULENAME]/model": https fetch: Get "[MODULENAME]/model?go-get=1": dial tcp [MYSERVER IP]: connect: connection refused
```

I am new to Golang and to Modules in generl. I tried to solve but somehow I am super confused.
I woul really appreciate any help.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you declared the `(*mutationResolver).CreateTodo` and `(*queryResolver).Todos` functions multiple times. First you defined them in `graph/resolver.go` file, and the second time in the `graph/schema.resolvers.go` file which is generated by gqlgen.

The `graph/schema.resolvers.go` file will be regenerated each time, and will contain all the resolver implementations that couldn't be matched from your "state", which is your `Resolver` struct, or from the `model` folder.

**Solutions**:

- You can just easily remove those declarations from the `graph/schema.resolvers.go` file
- Or just run the `gqlgen generate` command again, since it will find your implementations and remove those lines from the newly generated file

**A note on modules and import paths**:

Your first import path was great, if you have your `go.mod` file in the root, you can import all the packages inside them using the `yourmodulename/path/to/folder` format. In this case, the `yourmodulename/graph/model` is your import path.

Comment: Edit: Never mind thank you for helping me. I did not realise that it was a diffrent file. I should start learning reading again.